# MissingMethodException when using Groovy and JUnit 5 Assertions

Tags: groovy, junit, junit5, assertion

Trying to use JUnit 5 class Assertions, specifically assertAll() with Groovy.

Basic Java proves the following syntax:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    assertAll('heading',
        () -> assertTrue(firstName),
        () -> assertTrue(lastName)
    );
}
```

Since I'm stuck to Groovy v2.4, which does not support lambdas, what I do looks like (tried several options, however all of those provide the same error):

```
@Test
void 'Some test'() {
    assertAll('heading',
        { -> assert firstName },
        { -> assert lastName }
    )
}
```

Error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertAll() is applicable for argument 
types: (path.GeneralTests$_Some_test_closure10...)
values: [path.GeneralTests$_Some_test_losure10@1ef13eab, ...]
```

Looks like the problem is with assertAll() method itself, exception is quite obvious, however that's quite a challenge to get the possible solution, since I had to switch to Groovy from Python just recently.

Indeed, I am going to take some courses with Groovy in future, but you know, you always have to provide results for yesterday.

Would highly appreciate your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, you need to cast Groovy closure to `org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable` interface explicitly:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*

class Test {
    @Test
    void 'Some test'() {
        assertAll('heading',
                { assertTrue(true) } as Executable,
                { assertFalse(false) } as Executable)
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me, thank you! By any chance, do you have some good books, courses or other materials to recommend to work with Groovy, Geb, JUnit etc.? Looks like I'll need a bunch of those:)

P.S. Accepted your answer, though cannot upvote so far, since have <15 reputation. Will do this as soon as possible:)

Comment: @Alex, I'm not aware of good resources about Groovy / Geb (perhaps official documentation is good enough). However, in the case of unit testing, I'd definitely recommend this book: http://xunitpatterns.com/